# How to disable Pre-loading of pages or Prefetch in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, prefetch

I'm debugging a web application running in visual studio with some breakpoints on some code that runs on every request to my web application.

I find that in Chrome, as I type the URL past the host, it triggers a request for everything I type as I type it... As if Chrome prefetches the page to make it load faster or something.

While great for browsing the web, it's highly annoying when debugging code..

Anyone know of a way to disable, I've googled it a few different ways and what I can turn off I have, but it still makes requests as I type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under the **privacy** settings (`Settings -> show advanced settings... -> Privacy`) in `Chrome (Version 46.0.2490.80 m)` **uncheck** these two settings:

- Use a prediction service to help complete searches and `URLs` typed in
  the address bar or the `app launcher` search box
- Prefetch resources to load pages more quickly

Comment: I'll do some testing later to see if this is fixed in new versions, but I already had those disabled and it was still hitting my web server as I typed last I tested.  This is months ago though so it might not happen in new versions.

Comment: In Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 the second option is: Use prediction service to load pages more quickly

Comment: Does this setting still exist? I can't find it in Chrome 98.0.4758.80.

Answer (score 3):

Under `Settings` -> `Security and Privacy` -> `Cookies and other site data` (or by typing `chrome://settings/cookies?search=Security+and+Privacy` into the address bar and hitting "Enter" key), **uncheck** the following:

> `Preload pages for faster browsing and searching`
>
> Preloads pages that Chrome thinks you might visit. To do this, Chrome may use cookies, if you allow cookies, and may encrypt and send pages through Google to hide your identity from sites.

Additionally (to disable the "prediction service"), under `Settings` -> `You and Google` -> `Sync and Google services` (or by typing `chrome://settings/syncSetup?search=autocomplete` into the address bar and hitting "Enter" key), **uncheck** the below ([ref](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/56842041/where-s-the-use-a-prediction-service-to-help-complete-searches-and-urls-setting?hl=en)):

> `Autocomplete searches and URLs`
>
> Sends some cookies and searches from
> the address bar and search box to your default search engine.

Comment: These do sound like the correct settings. But even with both unchecked, there are still requests being made to ops.google.com, www.gstatic.com, fonts.gstatic.com and others. However they are not maed in incognito mode. Maybe an extension is interfering?

Comment: Could be possible. You could try disabling all (temporarily) here `chrome://extensions/`.

Comment: It's still happening even after a restart and even with all the extensions disabled. Seems like it must be a bug. I've awarded the bounty to this answer as I think it is a good update on the original answer.